# Rails ActiveRecord - Applying a condition or scope to multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose we have the following relations:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
  has_many :events
end

class Meetings < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :is_morning_meeting, -> { where.some.condition }
end

class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :is_morning_event, -> { where.some.condition }
end
```

Is there a way for me to grab entire `User` object, but specify the `is_morning_*` scope across these associations.

Something like:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings, -> () { is_morning_meeting if scope.morning_concerns }
  has_many :events, -> () { is_morning_event if scope.morning_concerns }

  scope :morning_concerns
end
```

used like so:

```
morning_user = user.morning_concerns
```

And if I call

```
morning_user.meetings
```

it should only return morning meetings

and if I call

```
morning_user.events
```

it should only return morning events

This might seem a bit specific, but I'm finding myself cornered here because of a GraphQL resolve flow.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned?

Comment: "_And if I call morning_user.meetings it should only return morning meetings_" - why not just adding another relation like `has_many :morning_meeting, <...>, class_name: 'Meeting'` and using it **explicitly** where appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom [`has_many` associations with a `scope`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) like this:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
  has_many :morning_meetings, -> { is_morning_meeting }, class_name: "Meeting"
  has_many :events
  has_many :morning_events, -> { is_morning_event }, class_name: "Event"
end
```

And can simply call those associations like normal associations:

```
user.morning_meetings
user.morning_events
```

Comment: You know, I didn't think of this, but I think this is an ideal solution! Thanks :)